# Excluding combinations of variables from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, the first is a list of all combinations of variables (that later in the code I will loop through)

DataframeA example:

```
 time_period    store_type  category_type
 month          store       lvl1
 month          store       lvl2
 month          format      lvl1
 month          format      lvl2
 week           store       lvl1
 week           store       lvl2
 week           format      lvl1
 week           format      lvl2
```

The second dataframe contains combinations that I would like to exclude from dataframeA before moving on in the code. A blank cell indicates that I want to exclude all of that type, for example in row one below I want to exclude all time periods with a combination of store and lvl1.

DataframeB example:

```
 time_period    store_type  category_type
                store       lvl1
 month          store       lvl2
```

I would like to apply the exclusion in such a way that DataframeB first removes combinations of store x lvl1 (i.e. removes rows 1 and 5 from DataframeA), then removes combinations of month x store x lvl2 (i.e. removes row 2 from DataframeA)

The resulting dataframe would end as:

```
 time_period    store_type  category_type
 month          format      lvl1
 month          format      lvl2
 week           store       lvl2
 week           format      lvl1
 week           format      lvl2
```

I have coded up a solution, but have had to rely on looping through the exclusion combinations one by one, so I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution :)

```
 all_exclusions <- NULL

 for (i in 1:nrow(dataframeB)) {

   # Find current row

   current_rows_data <-
     dataframeB %>%
     slice(i)

   # Number of combinations 

   num_vars <- (current_rows_data$time_period != "") + (current_rows_data$store_type != "") + (current_rows_data$category_type != "")

   # Exclude combinations

   exclusions <- 
     dataframeA %>%
     mutate(
       check = (time_period == current_rows_data$time_period) + 
               (store_type == current_rows_data$store_type) + 
               (category_type == current_rows_data$category_type)      
       ) %>%
     filter(check == num_vars)

   # Collate exclusions

   all_exclusions <- rbind_list(all_exclusions, exclusions)

   # Tidy up

   rm(exclusions)

 }

 # Remove exclusions

 dataframeA <- anti_join(dataframeA, all_exclusions)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need first to work a bit on `DataframeB` so it contains all the rows you want to remove from `DataframeA`:

```
for_all <- which(DataframeB$time_period=="")
DB <- rbind(DataframeB, 
            data.frame(time_period="week", DataframeB[for_all, 2:3], stringsAsFactors=F), 
            data.frame(time_period="month", DataframeB[for_all, 2:3], stringsAsFactors=F)
           )[-for_all, ]
```

Then you can do an "anti-join" either with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DataframeA)[!DataframeB, on=names(DataframeA)]
#   time_period store_type category_type
#1:       month     format          lvl1
#2:       month     format          lvl2
#3:        week      store          lvl2
#4:        week     format          lvl1
#5:        week     format          lvl2
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(DataframeA, DataframeB)
#Joining by: c("time_period", "store_type", "category_type")
#  time_period store_type category_type
#1       month     format          lvl2
#2       month     format          lvl1
#3        week     format          lvl1
#4        week     format          lvl2
#5        week      store          lvl2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue then I think is with the blank cells, because this is just a simplified example, in the full DataframeB there are more rows, with blanks in other columns - is there a way to generalise this filling of blank cells with all possible values?

Comment: I've thought about your suggestion and will go with the approach of filling the gaps but will create a unique list of time_periods from dataframeA and use a merge to expand dataframeB and fill the gaps

Comment: @SamGilbert Hi, I didn't have time yet to work on an edit but your way seems the right one :-)